# Usage de 'y' et 'en'

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-personnels, en, y

Dans cette phrase, comment utilise-t-on un pronom personnel ?

> Elle cherche une bague **en diamant**. (remplacer « en diamant »).

Sera-ce « en » ou « y » ?

Comment: I think you may be confusing adverbial pronouns with 'en' other meanings perhaps. In this case, it means a diamond ring (or a ring in diamond) How you have phrased it leads me to believe that you may mistakenly believe that in this case it acts as an adverbial pronoun (en or y) which it does not in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Ni n'un ni l'autre de ces mots ne conviennent.

- -- Elle cherche une bague en diamant ?
  -- Oui, elle cherche une **telle** bague. *ou, plus courant*
  -- Oui, elle cherche une bague de cette sorte.
  -- Oui, c'est une bague de cette sorte qu'elle cherche.

Cependant, pour remplacer « **bague en diamant** », « en »<sup>1</sup> convient (et seulement « en ») ; néanmoins « en » tout seul n'est pas suffisant.

- -- Alors elle cherche une bague en diamant ?
  -- Oui, elle **en** cherche **une**.
- -- Veut-il un bracelet en or ?
  -- Oui, il **en** veut **un**.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Ce qui peut être évident pour l'apprenant déjà assez avancé ne l'est peut être pas pour les débutants et il est donc utile de signaler qu'il ne faut pas confondre les deux « en » que l'on trouve dans les phrases ci-dessus ; ne pas penser que l'on remplace « bague en diamant » par le « en » qui se trouve dans cette locution, raccourcissant celle-ci pour s'en servir comme d'un représentant ; ce n'est pas ce dont il s'agit: ce « en » est une *préposition* et le « en » dans le remplacement est un *pronom*.</sub>

Comment: @subsexdexter C'est plutôt à moi qu'il incombe de remercier pour ce détail, comme je ne suis que «  l'amanuensis » ; d'autre part, je ne trouve rien d'anormal, tout au contraire, à attribuer le crédit qui revient à quelqu'un même en l'absence de commentaire, sauf, bien sûr, en cas d'abandon de  copyright par le véritable auteur.